# I am trying to do inheritance in Java and the extra varaibles that are outside the inheritance class aren't being shown when I display

Tags: java, inheritance

Inheritance is not completely working for me as the extra variables outside the inheritance class are not being displayed. When I input the employee details and input the wage it is accepted. But then it is not shown when I list all employees in database or when searching for an employee

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    public Employee(){ }

    public Employee (int id, int wage, String name, String surname){
        super(id,name,surname);
        this.wage = wage;
    }

    private int wage;

    public void SetWage(int wg){
        wage=wg;
    }

    public int GetWage (){
        return wage;
    }

    public String toString(){
       return "ID: " + this.GetId() + "\n"
            + "Name:" + this.GetName() + "\n"
            + "Surname:"  + this.GetSurname() + "\n"
            + "Wage: " + this.GetWage();
    }

}
```

Similarly the client class is not working. Also here is the code for the person class

```
public class Person{

    public Person(){
        pId = 0;
        pName = "";
        pSurname = "";
    }

    public Person (int id, String nm, String sn) {
        pId = id;
        pName = nm;
        pSurname = sn;
    }

    private int pId;
    private String pName;
    private String pSurname; 

    public int GetId(){
        return pId;
    }

    public void SetId(int id){
        pId= id;
    }

    public String GetName(){
        return pName;
    }

    public void SetName(String nm){
        pName = nm;
    }

    public String GetSurname (){
        return pSurname;
    }

    public void SetSurname(String sn){
        pSurname = sn ;
    }

    public String ToString(){
        return "ID: " + this.GetId() + "\n"
             + "Name:" + this.GetName() + "\n"
             + "Surname:" + this.GetSurname();
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What "extra variables outside the inheritance class" are you referring to? What is "not working"? Be more specific please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use it in the following way:

```
Person employee = new Employee()
```

you will not be able to use SetWage and GetWage functions because they are not part of Person object. If you want to use work that way you can declare them as abstract functions in Person class of instantiate your object differently: Employee employee = new Employee()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, order your class as follows: fields, constructors, methods. Try not to have constructors before the fields, it's rather hard to read.

Also, just like paisanco noted out in the comments - try to ask more specific questions, it's not easy to understand what is the problem.

Last thing - if I understand right, you probably can't access Person class fields, such as:

```
private int pId;
private String pName;
private String pSurname;
```

This is most likely problem of how you create your object.

Instead of

```
Emplyee emp = new Employee();
```

Try creating employee object in such manner:

```
Person pers = new Employee();
```

This should fix this and you should be able to access person class fields aswell.

And if you after that would like to access employee fields like wage and so on, you should cast the object to Employee object, e.g:

```
if (pers instanceof Employee) {
  ((Employee) pers).getWage();
}
```